# How to cancel a specific thread while using C++11 thread model or tbb thread class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, tbb

While using C++11 thread model or TBB thread class, how can I cancel other thread (If you are using pthread lib, you could cancel other thread using pthread_cancel)? 
Ps: is there the conception of thread cancellation point as pthread in C++11 thread model or tbb thread class?

Comment: As far as I understand, the thread has to collaborate and exit itself on demand.

Comment: Standard threads are not cancellable. TBB: http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_scheduler/cancellation.htm

Comment: Does your question relate to threads only? TBB is not about threads (but about high-level parallel constructs), it just provides compatibility layer for old compilers which miss std::thread.

Answer (score 2):

TBB provides thread class as a compatibility layer for C++03 which is as close to C++11 as possibly. Other libraries (e.g. [boost](/questions/tagged/boost)) also provide a thread class which doesn't have a `cancel()` method.

Thus the question is rather "how to cancel a thread in C++". And the answer is: there is no built-in cancellation, just [interrupt politely](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/interrupt-politely/207100682).

`pthread_cancel` is a bad idea for general C++ program since it does not respect objects lifetime.

Write your own cancellation point which reads a cancellation flag and if it is set, throws an exception to unwind the stack correctly.

```
std::atomic<bool> is_cancelled;
void check_cancel() {
    if(is_cancelled)
        throw std::runtime_error("cancelled");
}
```